# Segmentation error when changing values in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a matrix A which I am defining dynamically . Values of a and b is 9 so its a 9x9 matrix.

```
double **A = (double **) malloc(a * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      A[i] = (double *) malloc(b * sizeof(double ));
      }
```

Now when I am doing the following code , I get segmentation error . z=49 in this case

```
for(j=0; j<z; j++){
      for(i=0; i<z; i++){
          A[j][i]=1.0;
          }
          }
```

I tried changing the values of z and its working till z=30.
I am loping over the columns and then loop over the rows and change the value for specific elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allocating a data structure representing a 9 x 9 matrix.  You're attempting to assign values as if it had dimensions (at least) 49 x 49.  That grossly overruns the bounds of your object, producing undefined behavior.  A segmentation fault / segmentation error is a common manifestation of  undefined behavior arising from such a situation.

That the UB manifests differently for `z` between 10 and 30 is irrelevant.  In particular, if its manifestation happens to be consistent with your conclusion that "it works", that does not in any way mean that the program is correct or safe, nor does it say anything about how the UB should manifest for other values of `z`, or even that it should reliably manifest the same way for `z` in this range.

Answer (score 1):

If either the value of `a` or the value of `b` used to allocate arrays is less than the value of `z` then you indeed  can get a segmentation error because actually there will be undefined behavior accessing memory outside the allocated arrays.

So if `a` and `b` are equal to `9` then the variable `z` also shall not be greater than `9`.

Also if you want to use a square matrix then there is no great sense to use two different variables `a` and `b` to allocate arrays. It is enough and more clear to use only one variable throughout your program.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you could allocate a two-dimensional array the following way calling the function `malloc` only once:

```
int z = 49;

double ( *A )[z] = malloc( sizeof( double[z][z] ) );

for ( j = 0; j < z; j++ )
{
    for ( i = 0; i < z; i++ )
    {
        A[j][i] = 1.0;
    }
}

//...

free( A );
```

Comment: indeed? Does UB guarantee segfault?

Comment: @0___________ He said that he has a segmentation error.

Answer (score 1):

> I get segmentation error . z=49 in this case

If you allocate 9x9 array and try to access elements outside the matrix bounds you invoke Undefined Behaviour (UB).

Your `z` has to be **`9`** in this case not **`49`**